# Modifying mysql database for efficiency

Tags: php, mysql

Currently the company I am employed for stores page visits via mysql to give their client daily traffic stats. There table structure is:

visit_id, page_id, ts, ip, uri, site_id

So far there are 85 million rows....when only 2200 accounts exist.

The format it spits the stats to client is:

Total visits: XXXX
Last 24 hour visits: XXXX

What is the best way to restructure this while maintaining it's current functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing visit date is in a separate visit table, you'll get better throughput if you denormalize that.

Precalculating your results will make your stats query run a lot faster, below is a general idea of what you'd do.

```
CREATE TABLE stats_table (
,  site_identifier        INT
,  date_visited           DATE
,  visit_count            INT
,  INDEX(site_identifier)
);
```

Instead inserting into this table for every visit, you'd increment visit count.  Then you could query it like:

```
SELECT site_identifier, visit_count FROM stats_table where date_visited = 'today';

SELECT site_identifier, SUM(visit_count) AS `total_visits` FROM stats_table GROUP BY site_identifier;
```

You could combine those two queries, but it'll prolly be faster to query them separately.

Comment: It's based off of time stamp. It stores date and time there. In this same table.

Comment: That structure is pretty optimal as is, so long as it's indexed properly (an index on ts and ip).  You could also think about precalculating an aggregate table so when it comes time to generate a report you can just "SELECT * FROM visit_stats"

Comment: The issue is, it takes so long to generate the stat report to client.

Comment: I would precalculate the data you need for the report then.  Not sure how you're populating the original table, but try creating a new table that has everything already grouped, and write to it at the same time you write to the original table.  I've added a starting point for the table structure in my original answer.

Comment: Here is the query currently being used to populate client gui:
`
$daily_hits = $db->getValue("select count(distinct ip,date(ts),hour(ts)) from page_visits where site_id={$site->id} and ts>=date_sub(now(),interval 1 day)");
        $query = "select count(distinct ip,date(ts),hour(ts)) from page_visits where site_id={$site->id}";
//die($query);
 $total_hits = $db->getValue($query);
 if(!$total_hits) $hits_error = mysql_error();
 $stat = array();
?>
<p style="margin-left: 24px;">Last 24 Hours: <?PHP echo $daily_hits;?></p>
       <p style="margin-left: 24px;">Total: <?PHP echo $total_hits;?></p>`

Comment: Edit your original post with that query, highlight it, and click the formatting button, it looks like {}